# Using BERT (distilled) model in celery/redis task on heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, nlp, celery, huggingface-transformers

I am using a distilled bert model to perform question answering

https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad

Locally it all works fine, but when trying to use the model in my celery task, the worker thread logs show

> 2020-09-24T03:50:05.794556+00:00 app[worker.1]: 72%|███████▏  | 187M/261M [00:14<00:04, 15.5MB/s]
> 2020-09-24T03:50:19.779019+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=652M(123.2%)
> 2020-09-24T03:50:19.781651+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

The code below is where I my import, model loading and task takes place. Removing the imports and loading resolves the memory issue.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad")
@app.task
def evaluateQuestionAnswer():
```

I'm wondering if I need to use something like tensorflow serving

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

Or am I missing something about making models production ready?

Would using docker alleviate this loading problem?

Comment: Did you check https://redisai.io?

Comment: no, but will def look into that

Comment: You don't need tensorflow because your code is not using it.. I have no clue of heroku but the error message is pretty clear. It seems that you have some kind of memory limit. In general, a transformers model requires 500MB to 2GB memory.